# ¿Cómo valido un input ingresado comparándolo con un array en localStorage?

Tags: javascript, validación, condiciones, local-storage, input

Tengo que hacer una página que pueda ingresar y guardar los resultados de un partido de fútbol. Para ingresar los nombres de los equipos, se tiene que validar que sean los mismos ingresados en una página previa que guarde en un *array* en `localStorage`.

El problema es que al usar un `for` para recorrer el objeto de equipos, aunque el nombre sea `true` me lo reconoce como `false` y no se por qué.

Hice una función para validar y la llamo antes de guardar los datos de los resultados. Incluso he utilizado la consola para testear que se vea con el mismo nombre, y si es del mismo tipo, y lo es, pero sigue apareciendo `false` y no sé por qué.

```
function validateNames(name1) {
   let teams = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('teams'));
   let confirm1 = false;
   for (let i = 0; i < teams.length; i++){
      if (teams[i].name == name1) {
         confirm1 = true;
      }
   }   
   
   return (confirm1);
}

let team1Name = document.getElementById('team1-name').value;
let team2Name = document.getElementById('team2-name').value;

let auxiliar1 = validateNames(team1Name);
let auxiliar2 = validateNames(team2Name);
let auxiliar = auxiliar1 && auxiliar2;

if(auxiliar == true ) {
   //Instrucciones para guardar
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué hay en local storage cuando llamas a `validateName()`? `console.log(localStorage.getItem('teams'))`

Answer (score 0):

Aqui tienes, si descomentas la linea, para cogerlo del almacenamiento local y comentas el mock, deberia funcionar

```js
function validateNames(name1){
   //let teams = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('teams')); DESCOMENTA ESTA LINEA PARA PROBARLO EN TU ENTORNO
   let teams = JSON.parse("[{\"name\":\"equipo1\"}, {\"name\":\"equipo2\"},{\"name\":\"equipo3\"}]");
   let confirm1 = false;
        
    console.log(teams);
        
    for(let i = 0; i < teams.length; i++){
        if( teams[i].name == name1){
            confirm1 = true;
        }
    }   
    
    return (confirm1);
}
    

function validate(){
    let team1Name = document.getElementById('team1-name').value;
    let team2Name = document.getElementById('team2-name').value;

    let auxiliar1 = validateNames(team1Name);
    let auxiliar2 = validateNames(team2Name);
    let auxiliar = auxiliar1 && auxiliar2;
  
    if(auxiliar == true ){
       alert("equipos correctos")
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>

<body>
<br>
<br>
<label>resultado: </label><input type="button" onclick="validate()" value="validar"/>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<br>
<label>equipo1: </label><input id="team1-name" type="text" value="equipo1" />
<br>
<br>
<label>equipo2: </label><input id="team2-name"  type="text" value="equipo2" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ya pude resolverlo, muchas gracias. En realidad era una cuestión diferente a la que me plantean, al cambiar el orden de donde habia puesto el `let auxiliar1 = validateNames(team1Name); etc`  se soluciono, igual muchas gracias:') @Rddevelop @juanrporzo